# Why does C++ auto_ptr have two copy constructors and two assignment operators but one default constructor?

Tags: c++, stl

Why does it need two forms? Thanks

```
    explicit auto_ptr (T* ptr = 0) throw() 

    auto_ptr (auto_ptr& rhs) throw() 

    template<class Y>
    auto_ptr (auto_ptr<Y>& rhs) throw() 

    auto_ptr& operator= (auto_ptr& rhs) throw()

    template<class Y>
    auto_ptr& operator= (auto_ptr<Y>& rhs) throw()
```

Answer (score 7):

It has **one** copy constructor - the non-templated one.

The template constructor and assignment operator allow assignment of pointer types for which an implicit exists:

```
class A {}
class B : public A {}

B * b = new B();
A * a = b;       // OK!


auto_ptr<B> b(new B);
auto_ptr<A> a = b; // *
```

without the template versions, (*) wouldn't work, as the compiler treats `auto_ptr<A>` as a completely different type than `auto_ptr<B>`.

Comment: No, a static cast (which would allow A* to B* conversion, for example) is not used.  Implicit conversion is used.

Answer (score 6):

Because copy constructors cannot be templates.  If they only had the template version then the compiler would make one that would not work correctly.

Same for assignment op...I think.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does C++ auto_ptr have two copy constructors and two assignment operators but one default constructor?

It does not.

It has 1 default constructor (a constructor that takes 0 arguments)

```
explicit auto_ptr (T* ptr = 0) throw()
```

It has 1 copy constructor (a constructor that makes a copy from an object of the same type)

```
auto_ptr (auto_ptr& rhs) throw()
```

It has 1 assignment operator that is used to assign objects of the same type.

```
auto_ptr& operator= (auto_ptr& rhs) throw()
```

It has a fancy templated constructor that takes auto_ptr of other types (this is not a copy constructor it is just a normal constructor (though it is templated)).

```
template<class Y>
auto_ptr (auto_ptr<Y>& rhs) throw()
```

It has another assignment operator that takes different types of auto pointer (So yes this is another assignment operator but it is not a copy assignment operator (but a conversion assignment operator) as the rhs has a different type).

```
template<class Y>
auto_ptr& operator= (auto_ptr<Y>& rhs) throw()
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the non-templated versions is to allow `auto_ptr`s to the same type to be assigned / constructed.  The templated versions exist to allow construction / assignment from related, but not identical pointer types.

```
auto_ptr <Foo> f = new Foo(); // uses raw pointer constructor
auto_ptr <Foo> f2 = f;  // uses non-templated constructor
auto_ptr <const Foo> f3 = f2; // uses templated constructor   

auto_ptr <Foo> f4 = new foo();
f2 = f4; // uses non-templated assignment operator
f3 = f2; // uses templated assignment operator
```

Comment: Inheritance makes a better example of using the templates, but it applies to cv differences too.

Comment: @Fred, yes, inheritance is the more common case, but makes for a less succinct example.

Comment: Looks like two things got lost in the f4 declaration line, did you mean auto_ptr<Foo> f4 = new Foo()?